# "Log_In() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)" in Odoo 10.0

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I want to create a "Signup/Login Form" by odoo 10.0.

My code python :

```
class SinhVien(models.Model):   
     _name = "studentmanagement.sinhvien"

     Ten = fields.Char()
     GioiTinh = fields.Char()
     NgaySinh = fields.Char()
     LienLac = fields.Char()
     MatKhau = fields.Char()
     DiaChi = fields.Char()
     DangKyHocPhan = fields.Many2many('studentmanagement.khoahoc', 'Dang_Ky_Hoc_Phan', 'studentmanagement.sinhvien_id', 'studentmanagement.khoahoc_id', string ="dang ky hoc phan")
     _sql_constraints = [ ('LienLac', 'unique(LienLac)', 'Two student with the same user!') ]

     def Log_In(self, Account, Password):
         if Account is not None & Password is not None:
            test_prod_ids = self.search([('LienLac','=',Account),   ('MatKhau','=',Password)], limit=1, context=None)
            return {
              'name': ('My Profile'),
              'view_type': 'form',
              'view_mode': 'form',
              'res_model': 'studentmanagement.sinhvien',
              'view_id': False,
              'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            }
        else :
            return None
 class KhoaHoc(models.Model):
       _name = "studentmanagement.khoahoc"

       MonHoc = fields.Char()
       TinChi = fields.Integer()
       PhongHoc = fields.Char()
       GiaoVien = fields.Char()
```

LogIn_SignUp.xml :

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="LogIn_form_view">
        <field name="name">Logging</field>
        <field name="model">studentmanagement.sinhvien</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Logging">
                <group>
                    <field name="LienLac"/>
                    <field name="MatKhau"/>
                    <button string="Log In" type="object" name="Log_In"/>
                </group>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="LogIn_form_action">
        <field name="name">Log In</field>
        <field name="res_model">studentmanagement.sinhvien</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name='view_id' ref='LogIn_form_view'/>
    </record>

    <menuitem id="main_menu_entrance" name="entrance"/>
    <menuitem id="Log In" name="Log In" parent="main_menu_entrance" action="LogIn_form_action"/>
```

Form : [image]
And This is the error : [image]

I have searched a lot, but nobody have the same situation. I don't understand exactly such error, and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell for sure, but based on the stack trace, you might need to have `Log_In` just accept a single [**kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python):

```
def Log_In(self, **kwargs):
    Account = kwargs.get('Account')
    Password = kwargs.get('Password')
    if Account is not None & Password is not None:
    ...
```

Or possibly just:

```
def Log_In(self, args):
    Account = args.get('Account')
    Password = args.get('Password')
    if Account is not None & Password is not None:
    ...
```

Comment: The problem is that how the program can get text from 2 textbox fields in this :           <field name="LienLac"/>
                   <field name="MatKhau"/>, if we are not sure 'Account' and 'Password' are 2 arguments referenced by 2 text fields

Comment: There's an example in the Odoo documentation: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/fc2e80cb4bcc450762c7ac5cb82a3e2d88062b38/addons/point_of_sale/wizard/pos_details.xml and https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/dae737eca119227cdc4f341c0766cab9caec48bb/addons/point_of_sale/wizard/pos_details.py. It looks like the calls use `@api.multi` with only `self` as an argument. The Account and Password fields might already get populated (are they LienLac and Matkhau)?

Comment: XML :
<field name="LienLac"/>
 <field name="MatKhau"/>

Python :
def Log_In(self, args):
       Account = args.get('LienLac')
       Password = args.get('MatKhau')

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected my code and it works for me :

```
def Log_In(self, args):
    Account = args.get('LienLac')
    Password = args.get('MatKhau')
    if Account is not None and Password is not None:
         test_prod_ids = self.search([('LienLac','=',Account),('MatKhau','=',Password)], limit=1, context=None)
         if test_prod_ids:
            return {
               'name': ('My Profile'),
               'view_type': 'form',
               'view_mode': 'form',
               'res_model': 'studentmanagement.sinhvien',
               'view_id': False,
               'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
             }
       else:
          return None
    else :
         return None
```

Comment: You really should consider to read [Odoo Guidelines](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/guidelines.html) and [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and refactor your code after it.